# Extending django admin custom view for user

Tags: python, django

I have a database of businesses around my city, and I want to allow individual businesses to submit data to the database, but under their respective business names. my business table looks like this:

id,
business_name,
business_address,
business_city,
business_state,

so on and so fourth. There are other tables in the database, but they are tied to the id field of this Model. I want to use the admin console to confine usernames to business_id's, so businesses can login and submit data for their respective business.

Can I get this accomplished using the django admin console?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked st something like `django-guardian`?

Github: https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian

PyPi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-guardian

Comment: Hmm, ok. Thought there may be a simpler solution. Ie, create your own table and model?